# Scrapy Crawled 0 pages

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Есть такой код

```
import scrapy

class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_url = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = ".set"
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            NANE_SELECTOR = 'h1 ::text'
            yield {
                    'name' : brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                  }
```

При запуске скрапера он почему-то не видит моей страницы (как я могу предположить из-за ошибки). INFO: Crawled 0 pages.
ЕСли есть рекомендации как можно в короткие сроки ознакомитсья с данным фреймворка, прошу прислать мне ссылки на материалы. Заранее Вам спасибо!

Comment: Так у него есть прекрасная документация: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: Кстати, на https://brickset.com/sets/year-2016 проверка на робота стоит.